# position of element issue in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, position

I am using the following javascript function to get the absoulte position of an element

```
function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
      while (1) {
          curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
          if (!obj.offsetParent) {
              break;
          }
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
      }
  }
}
```

The  function is working fine in all browsers except IE .In IE also it works fine in full screen but when the browser is resized then this method returns incorrect offset.

Could you please help me out on this

Comment: why don't you use `while(obj){` in order to make you code short

Comment: please specify the version of IE that you're testing with. (Also check whether it's in quirks mode)

Comment: I am using IE8 and IE9 versions.The issue is with both verisons 8 and 9.In full screen,it is returning the absolute position correctly but when I do browser resize,it is returning incorrect values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to switch from using `offsetParent/Top/Left` to utilizing `getBoundingClientRect()` function (slightly enhanced). It should be more performant, because you don't have to loop through DOM and it should return correct results across browsers.

Your findPos function would look like this:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var gbcr = obj.getBoundingClientRect(),
        dE = document.documentElement,
        b = document.body,
        scrollY = window.pageYOffset || dE.scrollTop || b.scrollTop, /* 1 */
        scrollX = window.pageXOffset || dE.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft, /* 1 */
        top = gbcr.top + scrollY - dE.clientTop, /* 2 */
        left = gbcr.left + scrollX - dE.clientLeft; /* 2 */

    return { top: top, left: left };
}
```

1. `getBoundingClientRect()` doesn't take scroll into account, so you have to compensate that.
2. It is possible to set border on `<html>`, so without substracting it's value, the function could return incorrect element position relative to document.

Comment: You have to add the amount of pixels scrolled from top/left to the corresponding getBoundingClientRect() property. It's already integrated into the function I posted, see scrollY/scrollX variables.